# Download file through Android Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make it so that a file from my web server can be downloaded to an Android mobile device. I want the user to be able to press a Download button on the site, and then they will have the option to save it on there phone's sd card.

The only way I can think of doing this is by using FTP, and having the button navigate the user to ftp://username:pass@webserver/file.blah

Is there another way, using strictly HTML5 and JS?

I have tried using the download tag, but that doesn't seem to work. Instead of downloading the image it redirects them to the page with the image on it.

```
<a href="/img/cir.png" download="cir.png">Link</a>
```

Comment: You can just have a regular HTTP route to the where ever that file is being served from your server/CDN. Android browsers should be able save that to the storage of the phone. You can of course tweak stuff with javascript where you have the link.

Comment: I have tried using the download tag, and it seems to only redirect them to that page.

<a href="/img/cir.png" download="Download">Link</a>

Comment: 1. Are you using browser that supports the download attribute? 2. You might need to write `download="Download"` this with the file extension. So, `Download.png` Maybe that helps?

Comment: Download was filler text for the example, and that did not fix the problem. Yes the browser supports the download attribute. I will modify it so that the example matches the code exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### HTML5 solution

To force downloading a file, **if you are using HTML5**, then you can use the download attribute by defining the anchor tag like this.

```
<a href="/path-to-image/image.png" download="download.png">Download Link</a>
```

### Server-side solution

It is likely that the user's browser doesn't support the download attribute. Check [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). So the other solution invloves the server-side. You can use the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header. Serve this as one of the headers of the HTTP response for the download route. This will force the browser to download the file as an *attachment*.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.png"
```

[RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) Read section `19.5.1`